# Do possessive pronouns always replace?

Tags: nouns, possessive-pronouns, possessive-adjectives

Possessive Pronouns replace *Possessive adjectives* and *nouns*
For eg - That is my(possessive adjective) ball(noun)
That is mine(possessive pronoun) or
That ball is mine(possessive pronoun) 
That ball is  my (possessive adjective) ball(noun)

Now my question is : In the sentence , A friend of mine -- What does this mean ? 
I mean why doesn't it mean A friend of my friend ?

Possessive pronouns are used to show who owns something so we can say a friend of mine to tell that I own that friend , but isn't it weird that how the possessive adj and noun is are replaced For eg -- A friend of mine(possessive pronoun )  changes to 
A friend of my(possessive adj) friend(noun) ?? plz answer my question !!

Comment: A friend of mine is one of my friends. A friend of a friend is not.

Answer (score 1):

"A friend of mine" uses the double possessive, since it uses both "of" and a possessive noun/pronoun. The reason we have double possessives in English in the first place is to help eliminate ambiguity. For example, "a picture of me" is a picture that I'm in, while "a picture of mine" is a picture I own.

I'm not entirely sure why it came to be used in "a friend of X", but it's idiomatic.

Also, the expression you would get if you replaced the pronoun with a noun is:

> A friend of Shumroz's

Answer (score -1):

In the phrase "**a friend of mine**", "mine" refers to all of the speaker's friends, and "of" means something like "out of" or "from among". So the whole phrase can be interpreted as "**a friend from among my group of friends**". The phrase identifies some person as belonging to the speaker's group of friends.